# SQL getting data using other table + a value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables

### following

user_id
following_id

### users

user_id
user_name
what not

What I am trying to do is trying to match all the following_id for results:

```
SELECT * FROM `following` WHERE `user_id` = X
```

With:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_fullname` LIKE  '%a%' AND  `user_id` = (FOLLOWING ID FROM FIRST RESULTS)
```

Though I have no idea how to start this. If someone could help me that would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is edit the user_id and fullname in the where clause depending on what you want to search for

```
select * from following f
inner join users u on f.user_id = u.user_id
where u.user_id = X
and u.fullname like '%a%'
```

Comment: A little editing and trial & error made that work perfectly. Thanks